# ScrollView not working properly in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a text view in the scroll view. I set the height of the scroll view by `textView.frame.size.height`

Here is the code which i have tried

```
    textView.sizeToFit()

    let myViewController = UIViewController()
    let viewWidth = myViewController.view.frame.size.width

    let height = textView.frame.size.height

    scrollView.frame.origin.x = 0.0
    scrollView.frame.origin.y = 0.0

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(viewWidth,  height)
```

In iPhone 6s simulator, all content shows on the simulator correctly.

But for iPhone 5s simulator, all content not shown.

Again for iPhone X simulator, some empty space is shown in the bottom side.

What is the problem ?

Comment: show your tried code or screen shot

Comment: It will be great if you share the code or a screen shot for better understanding.  You can set scrollView.contenSize.height = //your required height . in your code.

Comment: Not sure of what's the purpose of adding a text view into a scroll view, it might inappropriate.

Comment: I have shared my code.

Comment: @Ahmad F, In my project, i have some textview which will not fit in the normal view. So, I tried with scroll view. Any better suggestion ?

Comment: You could create a table view instead, a cell for the text (dynamic height) and the rest of the cells contains the other content of the scroll view. Do not add a nested scroll view inside another scroll view, it is a bad practice.

Comment: First you have to change the height of textView based on its content you need to find out correct height of textview then I think it should work.

Comment: @Ahmad F, In table view cell, some cell may contain tow column, I also tried it but not work for me . When i scroll up and down, which cell might contain only one column, it also comes with tow column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UITextView inherits from UIScrollview. That is - a textview IS a scrollview.

Without further information, I'd say you really don't want to put a textview into a scrollview and adjust the heights as you have done. Just put a textview into your view straight and see if this solves your problem

Comment: i have some textview which will not fit in the normal view. So, what should i do ?

Comment: Textviews auto-scroll-me-do so will scroll naturally when you have too much text for the space. Try it.

Comment: I do not want scrolling enable.

Comment: There is a button in the inspector to set dynamic type "automatically adjusts font" and you can untick scrolling enabled. But Why would you put it inside a scrollview if you wouldn't want scrolling enabled?

Answer (score 0):

try following code

let height = textView.frame.size.height instead of height = textView.frame.maxY